# why does htop meter show >90% while table is 0.0%?

Tags: top, htop

Why do the progress meters across the top of the screen in `htop` show CPU usage consistently above >90% while the numbers in the table below show a nearly idle system with CPU usage and load average at 0.0%?

[image: partial htop screen grab]

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I am also on a Dreamhost VPS (virtual private server).

Comment: BTW, look at my example, it's even worse: http://demo.ddesign.si/temp/dh3.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`htop` is unaware it is running on a kernel level virtualized environment ([Dreamhost VPS](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/VPS-related_topics) is using [VServer](http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org) technology). It is then showing the CPU usage for all the OS instances sharing the same kernel, not just yours.

Have a look to [`vtop`](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/VPS-related_topics) output which sho ws all processes sharing the CPUs, not just the ones in your container.

If `vtop` is not installed, and this is probably expected for a commercial solution as one wouldn't like to a customer to see what processes are running other customers, there is no way to fix the issue from inside your container, unless patching `top` source to compute CPU usage instead of getting it from the kernel statistics.

It might do it by summing up CPU usage of all the processes running in your VServer, e.g.:

```
ps aux | awk '
    {cpu+=$3; ram+=$6} 
    END {printf("cpu: %d%%, RAM: %.2f MiB\n",cpu,ram/1024) }'
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation; `top` reports similarly to htop on this machine. Vtop not tested as not installed. Marking this as *accepted* because it answers "why?", though it doesn't address the implicit "and what can be done about it?", as that was unspoken

Answer (score 5):

This sort of inconsistency is usually indicative of high processor usage by kernel threads, which aren't displayed in `htop` by default. To display them, in `htop` go to `Setup`, then `Display options`, and then uncheck `Hide kernel threads`. This should allow you to see the thread(s) that are responsible.

You can also disable this behaviour by setting `hide_kernel_threads` to 0 in `~/.htoprc`.

Comment: thanks Chris. I did that but the table values are still 0%. Maybe this is something peculiar to running in a virtual machine? The host is Virtual Private Server (on Dreamhost.com).

Comment: For me, this is the more correct answer. I had a process that was taking up a lot of CPU from the kernel, and it wasn't showing up in the user space processes.

Comment: ...except that the HTop CPU meters show kernel time in red and user time in green, and we can clearly see it's nearly all green.

Answer (score 2):

Try launching `htop` with `sudo`. You need root access to see those active threads in the table.

Comment: I don't know how well or not this works on regular virtualized environments, if there is such a thing as regular, but doesn't work on dreamhost VPS.